# VBA for splitting the existing sheet using the values in drop down

Tags: drop-down-menu

I have created a file which is having a drop down list of names vlookup on Sheet1 with another sheet. Hence, one name is selected the values will be displayed on the Sheet1 as vlookup arranged.

I need a VBA for that dropdown list having cell (B4), Hence it should be split into multiple worksheets with the specific names.

Can anyone help?

- Shane -

Comment: Have you written any code so far?

Comment: No I didnt created any codes so far

Comment: Still no reply?